# python: modify array from parent method in child method

Tags: python, arrays, class, methods

I have a parent class as follows:

```
class student:
    def __init__(self, name, age, field):
            self.name = name
            self.age = age
            self.field = field

    def abilities(self):
        abs = ["study", "drink", "party"]
        action = np.random.choice(abs, replace = True)
        return(action)
```

Now upon graduation this student becomes a grown-up and his abilities change:

```
class adult(student):
    def abilities(self):
        super().abilities()
        abs.append("work")
        abs.remove("party")
        if action == work:
            print("paying off that student loan")
```

This does not work. The error I get is: `name 'abs' is not defined`.

Now I tried to access the `abilities` method in the parent class by using `super().abilities.abs` but then I am referring to the object the function returns and with `self.abilities.abs`, but then I refer to the class.

Any suggestions as to how to access the array within the parent method from the child are much appreciated.

Comment: An adult is not a kind of student. Inheritance isn't appropriate here. You can create an instance of `adult` *given* an instance of `student`, though, or have a `Person` class whose instances can be in either a "student" state or an "adult" state (though I would recommend against that).

Comment: Use `self.abs` in all instances of `abs`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few flaws in the code you wrote:

1. You are overwritting a built in function `abs` in your code. This should not be done.
2. You are calling `super().abilities()`, which returns a value without storing and using it.
3. When calling `abs.append("work")` you are trying to assign a value to a build in function and not the local variable `abs` from the parent. Extracting this to a object variable solves the issue. See, `self.abs` in the constructor
4. The adult `abilities` method is not returning anything.
5. You are not calling the super constructor in adult, which results in adult not storing any of the values passed in the constructor.

A fixed version could look as follows:

```py
import numpy as np

class student:
    def __init__(self, name, age, field):
            self.name = name
            self.age = age
            self.field = field
            self.abs = ["study", "drink", "party"]

    def abilities(self):
        
        action = np.random.choice(self.abs, replace = True)
        return action


class adult(student):
    
    def __init__(self, name, age, field):
        super(adult, self).__init__(name, age, field)
        
        self.abs.append("work")
        self.abs.remove("party")
    
    def abilities(self):
        action = super().abilities()
        
        if action == "work":
            print("paying off that student loan")

        return action
```

In addition to solving this issue, you should review the object inheritance structure as mentioned in the comment by @chepner.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your elaborate comments @mpSchrader. Could it be that some of your comments refer to differences between python 2.x and 3.x? In any case, I have only one doubt about the definition ```action = super().abilities()```. It appears that the phrase "paying off that student loan" is also returned if other actions than work are selected. I do not manage to pin down what the exact issue is though.

Comment: You are welcome.
I was testing it with Python 3, but it should also work with Python2. 

Currently it would print `paying off that student loan` an then return the current action value. If you would want to return `paying off that student loan` if the action is `work` then you can replace the print row with `return "paying off that student loan"`

Comment: Check! I tried defining the action as the print statement, but I forgot to return it in the same conditional statement. Thanks a lot for sharing your insights!

Comment: Sure. I am glad it helped and answered all your questions.

Comment: If the answer above helped you, could you accept it to signal other users that this is a helpful answer?

Comment: Apologies, I thought I'd accepted it. Instead I only upvoted.